# Changing my iTerm2 style after updating to zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm using iTerm2 for my Macbook Pro and have the following in my ~/.bash_profile which worked to update the style preferences for iTerm2 before updating to zsh

```
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias ll='ls -l'

function prompt {
  local BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
  local BLACKBOLD="\[\033[1;30m\]"
  local RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
  local REDBOLD="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local GREENBOLD="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
  local YELLOWBOLD="\[\033[1;33m\]"
  local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  local BLUEBOLD="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  local PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
  local PURPLEBOLD="\[\033[1;35m\]"
  local CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
  local CYANBOLD="\[\033[1;36m\]"
  local WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
  local WHITEBOLD="\[\033[1;37m\]"
  local RESETCOLOR="\[\e[00m\]"

  export PS1="\n$RED\u $PURPLE@ $GREEN\w $RESETCOLOR$GREENBOLD\$(git branch 2> /dev/null)\n $BLUE[\#] → $RESETCOLOR"
  export PS2=" | → $RESETCOLOR"
}

prompt

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/ivanteong/bin

source '/Users/ivanteong/lib/azure-cli/az.completion'
```

After updating to zsh (because it says I needed to do it since Apple replaces bash with zsh as the default shell in macOS Catalina which is the OS I'm using now), I lost all my preferences. I tried to read up online, creating ~/.zprofile and ~/.zshrc files but I don't know what to put in them, even when I copy/paste what was in bash into them, it still doesn't load up the style I want and will have the following error:

```
prompt:19: bad math expression: operand expected at `\#'
```

Can someone help me get back the terminal window style I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running High Sierra.  I don't know if you just updated the software and still have the bash settings in your system, but if that is the case you should be able to switch back to bash if that is easier. I found [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/) website explains it, but simply, change back to bash with:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

My knowledge of shells is very basic, so hopefully this helps.

Comment: Catalina simply changes which shell is used for new user accounts by default, from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/zsh`. `/bin/bash` is still the same 3.2 version of `bash` shipped with previous operating systems.